# How to compile a query with 2 parameters

Tags: scala, slick, currying

Now sure how to do this correctly, I'm trying to do this:

```
def byId(id: Column[Int], locationId: Column[Int]) = {
  for {
    m <- users if m.id === id && m.locationId == locationId
  } yield m
}

val byIdCompiled = Compiled(byId _)  // ???????????? how to pass second parameter?

def getById(id: Int, locationId: Int): Option[User] {
  byIdCompiled(id, locationId).firstOption
}
```

How do I curry a function with 2 parameters when compililng my slick query?

Comment: Have you tried this? (If so, what errors are you getting?) The reason I ask is because [according to the docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0-M2/queries.html#compiled-queries) this should already just work.

Comment: I'll try again, I think I was doing Compiled(byId _, _) before, I gave on trying.

Comment: The way you use _, it means the whole parameter list, not just a single parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The example provided in Slick docs uses single underscore to encode muiltiple parameters.

http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/queries.html

```
def userNameByIDRange(min: Column[Int], max: Column[Int]) =
  for {
    u <- users if u.id >= min && u.id < max
  } yield u.first

val userNameByIDRangeCompiled = Compiled(userNameByIDRange _)

// The query will be compiled only once:
val names1 = userNameByIDRangeCompiled(2, 5).run
val names2 = userNameByIDRangeCompiled(1, 3).run
```

Comment: I get the error 'application does not take parameters' by the parameters for byIdCompiled.